# RequireJS and Globals

Tags: requirejs, global-variables, require, js-amd

I have a number of event handlers in my page that were accessing global functions (functions defined in Script tags on the page). For instance:

```
<button id="ClearText" onclick="cleartb()">Clear Text Box</button>
```

That cleartb() function simply sits on the page:

```
<script>
function cleartb()
{
  vm.essayText('');
  return;
}
</script>
```

Now, vm is my page's view model (but for this question, all that matters is that it was simply a global variable available to the entire page) and I use functions and values it exposes in several event handlers, alert messages, etc.

The problem is that I've moved the definition of vm into a RequireJS AMD module called vm.js:

```
define(["knockout", "jquery"], function (ko, $) {

  var essayText = 'Hello World!';

  ...

  return {
    essayText: essayText
  }
});
```

When my onlick event handler runs or I refer to vm in any manner, I get a "vm undefined" error (as expected).

## Question 1:

How can I give my page access to the vm variable defined in an AMD module especially if I don't want to "pollute" the global namespace? Is there a best-practice here?

## Question 2:

Ultimately, I don't even want cleartb() on the page because it really is a view-model-specific operation. Although I think I can figure out what to do once I have the (an?) answer to Question 1, I would be interested to know how best to move the cleartb function into the vm AMD module so that I still can call it from my onlick event handler.

Note that I want values and function still to be exposed from a vm variable so that I can continue to use vm.cleartb() or inspect the value of vm.essayText() (it's a KO observable). (In other words, I don't want to solve the problem with a cleartb(vm) solution.)

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function cleartb()
{
  vm.essayText('');
  return;
}
alert(window.cleartb);
</script>
```

Actually, this way is already pollute the global `window` variable. So I think your first requirement don't make sense. And then you can do this way:

```
define(["knockout", "jquery"], function (ko, $) {

  var essayText = 'Hello World!', varToBeExported;

  ...
  window.varToBeExported = {
   'cleartb': cleartb
 };
  return {
    essayText: essayText
  }
});
```

But if unnecessary, you should using requireJs way - `require(['your moudle'],....` .

Comment: Point valid about my Question 1--I am already "polluting" the global namespace with my stated goal. But that makes me think: Is the way to avoid such polluting to use Require() calls everywhere I would likely otherwise use a global var? For instance, should my button's onclick event handler look like this?--
    `<button id="ClearText" onclick="Require(["vm"],function(vm){vm.cleartb();});">Clear Text Box</button>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how `varToBeExported` gets exported in your example.

Comment: Sorry. I forget to declare `varToBeExported` under window. I had fixed it. I don't know if there's some other way to get around this. Let's expect one hero together. :-)

Comment: I am mulling-over your suggestion--one that I had considered in my own efforts to resolve this issue. There is a big overall problem, however, and it has to do with the asynchronousity of RequireJS. Even if we expose varToBeExported to the main page as a window/global variable, the fact is that it might not be available to the rest of the page when the page makes references to it. Imagine someone clicking the button before RequireJS has asynchronously processed the vm module... Can I ensure that all asynch modules get loaded before <script> tags/event attribs on the page are processed?